# Django AngularJS Tornado Websocket - User Session Timeout Example

Tags: django, angularjs, session, tornado

How to setup user session expiry using Django AngularJS Websocket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django AngularJS Tornado - How to User Session Timeout Example

I have created a web application using Django 1.7b, DRF and AngularJS. To handle the session timeout, I wanted to auto log out user from the angular session if the session has expired on the Django side using server side push events (tornado).

I tried using the documentation but there were no good self explanatory examples provided for the same. After two days of brainstorming, I was able to implement it successfully. Just sharing this simple example for others.

This example serves multiple clients. Pass a token from the browser to open a connection. This token is passed to the websocket.py module and after 5 seconds of sleep, the same token is broadcast on the requested client browser. The code is shown below.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Regular expression groups in URL pattern are passed as arguments to "open"
method of tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler
"""

from tornado.web import Application
from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import time

class SampleWebSocket(WebSocketHandler):
    clients = []
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self, userid):
        self.clients.append(self)
        print ("connection_initiated")
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            self.write_message("%s" % userid)

    def on_close(self):
        self.clients.remove(self)
        self.write_message("connection_closed")

app = Application([
    (r'/user/([0-9]+)', SampleWebSocket),
    ],)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_server = HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.bind(8888)
    http_server.start(0)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

Execute this module using the following command.

```
$: python3 websocket.py
```

Create two HTML files (index1.html and index2.html) with the following code and open it in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tornado WebSocket Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="token" value="76c7ea95f0e51fb9b047dfe7aab4ff3c099505e4" />
  <button id="connect">Connect</button>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <script>
  var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  };

  $('connect').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    var token = $('token').value;

    var sock = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8888/token/' + token);
    sock.onopen = function () {
      console.log('opened.');
    };
    sock.onclose = function () {
      console.log('closed.');
    };
    sock.onerror = function () {
      console.log('error.');
    };
    sock.onmessage = function (evt) {
      $('result').innerText = evt.data;
      alert(evt.data);
    };
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Once you click connect with a value, a bidirectional connection will be opened and data will be pushed from the server to the client.

To integrate this with your Django code, just add django environment in the python code and start using the models. To setup the Django's environment, add the following code to your python websocket.py module at the top.

```
import os
import sys

# Setup Django environment so that we can access Django models
sys.path.append(path to your project directory)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
django.setup()
```

Once this configuration is done, you are all set to setup a websocket connection between the server and the client. Hope this helps someone.

Tornado - http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/